# Insert nonbreaking space and nonbreaking hyphen - rmarkdown to word document

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, officer, officedown

Is there a way to insert a nonbreaking space/hyphen when rendering a word document from rmarkdown? In MS Word, these two are special characters a user can insert with a key shortcut or manually. I'm wondering if this operation can be done from rmarkdown code, for example using officer/officedown packages?

[image]

Comment: I found this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47504157/how-to-insert-non-breaking-space-in-word-xml-using-java. In rmarkdown I can use knitr::asis_output("\u00A0") to insert a non-breaking space. I still need to find a unicode charater for non-breaking hyphen.

Comment: Also worth trying HTML codes  `&nbsp;`  and `&#8209` ?

Answer (score 2):

You could add a non-breaking space using the UTF-8-symbol `\u00a0` and a non-breaking hyphen (hope I got it right) using `\u2014`.

```
library(officer)

doc <- read_docx() |> 
  body_add_par(value = "Non-breaking\u00a0space") |> 
  body_add_par(value = "Non-breaking\u2014space")

print(doc, "foo.docx")
```

[image]

The option I used to figure out these codes was to create a docx with the special characters which I scraped using `officer::docx_summary()`. Here is a minimal reprex of this approach:

```r
library(officer)

fn <- tempfile(fileext = ".docx")

doc <- read_docx() |> 
  body_add_par(value = "Hello\u00a0World") |> 
  body_add_par(value = "Hello\u2014World")

print(doc, fn)

x <- read_docx(fn)

x <- officer::docx_summary(x)

stringi::stri_escape_unicode(x$text)
#> [1] "Hello\\u00a0World" "Hello\\u2014World"
```

Comment: Thanks @stefan, I found a solution using only knitr and the proper unicode character for my purpose is U+2011

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, thanks to this post [How to insert non breaking space in word xml using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47504157/how-to-insert-non-breaking-space-in-word-xml-using-java)

Non-breaking space and non-breaking hyphens have their own unicode encodings.
In my rmarkdown code I can use

```
    ABC`r knitr::asis_output("\U00A0")`DEF # sapce
    ABC`r knitr::asis_output("\U2011")`DEF # hyphen
```

Comment: Great you figured out a solution for yourself. Just in case: I added a reprex of the approach I took to figure out the unicodes.